# MEF InheritedExport hiding?

Tags: inheritance, import, export, mef

Apologies for the vague question framing.

Here is the situation. I have ParentA in Assembly1( class library). ParentA exports typeof ParentA

Now another product team wants to override some of the  behaviour of ParentA, in ChildA and deploy their Assembly - Assembly2, which holds a reference to Assembly1 (obviously).

The requriement is that ParentA is completely hidden by ChildA and all containers that import ParentA should now get a reference to an instance of ChildA instead. Standard Inheritance stuff.

BUT - Would MEF export instances of both ParentA AND ChildA?

How would i work around this situation ?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you rename `ChildA` to `ClassB` halfway in your question?

Comment: @Wim - sorry about that. renamed the classes to be clearer. Was posting at 3 am in the morning

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are / were looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee155691.aspx#avoiding_discovery

This is what it says:

> In some cases, you may want to prevent a part from being discovered as
>   part of a catalog. For example, the part may be a base class intended
>   to be inherited from, but not used. There are two ways to accomplish
>   this. First, you can use the `abstract` keyword on the part class.
>   Abstract classes never provide exports, although they can provide
>   inherited exports to classes that derive from them.
>
> If the class cannot be made abstract, you can decorate it with the
>   `PartNotDiscoverable` attribute. A part decorated with this attribute
>   will not be included in any catalogs. The following example
>   demonstrates these patterns. `DataOne` will be discovered by the
>   catalog. Since `DataTwo` is abstract, it will not be discovered. Since
>   `DataThree` used the `PartNotDiscoverable` attribute, it will not be
>   discovered.

```
<Export()>
Public Class DataOne
    'This part will be discovered 
    'as normal by the catalog.
End Class

<Export()>
Public MustInherit Class DataTwo
    'This part will not be discovered
    'by the catalog.
End Class

<PartNotDiscoverable()>
<Export()>
Public Class DataThree
    'This part will also not be discovered
    'by the catalog.
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

When MEF finds two exports for `ClassA` when it only expects one, it will throw a `CompositionException` saying that there is a cardinality problem. It doesn't know how to choose between both.

There is a way around this: if you pass multiple export providers to a container, the container will query each export provider in turn when it looks for an export. The first export provider to provide the part, wins.

In the following example the exports provided by assemblies in the "customized" subfolder override the exports provided by assemblies in the executable's folder.

```
var defaultExportProvider = 
    new CatalogExportProvider(new DirectoryCatalog(".","*"));
var customizedExportProvider = 
    new CatalogExportProvider(new DirectoryCatalog(@".\customized"));
var container = new CompositionContainer(
    customizedExportProvider, defaultExportProvider);
defaultExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
customizedExportProvider.SourceProvider = container;
```

**edit**:

Since the described solution isn't satisfactory, I can only assume that you are using `ImportMany` rather than `Import`. In that case you would indeed still get both exports, and you will have to add some [metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide) on them. You can then write code in your importing class which decides which import is the "best". See also this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/04/01/overriding-mef-metadata.aspx) by [Daniel Plaisted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509/daniel-plaisted).

Comment: i must have not phrased the question correctly. Let's assume that i can import a list of ParentA's into a collection. The issue is that one of the modules wants to HIDE the export of the base class and only export the inherited class. How would that be possible ?